# How do I get jasmine tests to ignore something on parent.window?

Tags: angularjs, typescript, jasmine

I have a Typescript/Angular app that runs in an iframed window. In the app, I'm using the [intl-tel-input](https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input) module to format & validate our phone number inputs. Intl-tel-input puts 'intlTelInputUtils' functions on the $window object. When testing the app locally without the iframe, I was able to successfully call the methods like (note the  surrounding window is just to satisfy the Typescript compiler:

```
(<any>window).intlTelInputUtils.getExtension(phoneNumber.userInput, phoneNumber.countryCode);
```

and get tests to pass by mocking the window.intlTelInputUtils object:

```
$window.intlTelInputUtils = {
            'getExtension': function () { return ''; },
            'formatNumber': function () { return ''; },
            'isValidNumber': function () { return true; }
        };
```

But of course this doesn't work once we're in the embedded iframe window. IntlTelInputUtils now appears at parent.window.intl....

I tried changing the method call to:

```
(<any>parent.window).intlTelInputUtils.getExtension(phoneNumber.userInput, phoneNumber.countryCode);
```

but I'm unable to push it to the server to see if that'll work (will it??) until I can get the Jasmine tests to pass. I tried changing the mock to:

```
$parent.$window = {
            'intlTelInputUtils': {
                'getExtension': function () {
                    return '';
                },
                'formatNumber': function () {
                    return '';
                },
                'isValidNumber': function () {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        };
```

But I realize this isn't correct.

How do I correctly mock parent.window.intlTelInputUtils in my tests??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will solve your problem but have you tried to add a spy to that specific call? For instance:

```
it('my test name', inject(function ($window) {
     spyOn($window.intlTelInputUtils, 'getExtension');

     ...

}));
```

And ofc you need to ensure that you and use `$window` on your code and not `window` directly.

Comment: I havent tried that, but the issue is I had to change my code from $window to parent.$window. So would I spy on parent.$window instead?

Comment: I would try that, yes. And, if needed, there is not problem in spying both. :)